# Mapview in Android Project

Tags: android, google-maps, build, google-maps-api-3

I am making one project in which use of map-view is required.
I have done map-view activity which requires Google API and it is running perfectly.

Now, I want to use that map-view in my main application which is build target 2.3.3 but when I change the android build target in eclipse and try to run ,it is not running properly.

Both the projects,main project as well as map project running very well separately, but when merged and needed to change the build target to use Google API , the main project is not running.

Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to generate a new map api for your map. The keystore you used for your 1st project might be different to the one you used for your 2nd project. Your map api depends on your keystore. So if your keystore changes, you must also generate a new map api. If you are using an invalid map api, your map won't load.

Comment: I have not created key-stores yet, it is still in eclipse development only

Comment: Are you, by any chance, programming from 2 different computers? When you are still on the development process, Eclipse is the one who is generating your keystore. You can view the location of your keystore at Windows > Android > Preferences > Build > Default debug keystore. If you are programming from two different computers, the keystore that will be generated for you will also be different.

Comment: actually the problem was I had to copy all the files of other project to the project of mapExample..

Comment: Well, it's nice to hear that you were able to solve your problem. :)